# Is this a safe / correct implementation of a variadic list argument used to simplify setting "pinMode"?

Tags: c++, arduino

##### Code (C++):

I'm new to C++ so I'm not sure if this is safe:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

void pin_mode(uint8_t pins[], uint8_t mode) {
  const int length = *(&pins + 1) - pins;
  for (size_t i = 0; (signed)i < length; i++) {
    pinMode(pins[i], mode);
  }
}
```

I have multiple pins that have the same pin setting, I'd like to set their values on one line instead of having 12 + lines that call the same function.

##### Usage:

```cpp
pin_mode([PIN_1, PIN_2, PIN_3, PIN_4], OUTPUT);
```

Is this a safe / correct implementation?

Comment: `*(&pins + 1) - pins` looks *invoking undefined behaviour*. Did you try both implementation & call, do they work?

Comment: Do you need a C++ or a C solution? The complete answers rely on that. But the way you implemented that function looks very much like a huge bug.

Comment: Sometimes I'm using `int8_t pins[] = {2,3,5,9,8,7};` and later `for (int8_t pin : pins) pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);`.

Comment: @greybeard I tried using `Serial.println` to determine if each pin was being set as an `OUTPUT` pin, and it does produce the desired result.

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm looking for a C++ solution. This code is for an Arduino project with a C++ codebase.

Comment: (Far as memory serves, (I asked that way when the question was at CR -and OT) `&pins + 1` for `pins[]` is the same as `pins + 1`, and `(&pins + 1) - pins` was just 1. But `*(&pins + 1)` is `pins[1]`, and what should be the meaning of `pins[1] - pins`? [Jerry Coffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72034562/3789665) looks solid advice.)

Comment: @greybeard Looking at git (before using the answer below), I had replaced that with `(sizeof(pins) / sizeof(*pins))` to determine the length of the array, that was a development mistake that I corrected after asking this question.

Comment: @LogicalBranch so far KIIV's comment is the simplest solution. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing this, I'd pass the array by reference, so the compiler would compute its size for me:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

template <size_t N>
void pin_mode(uint8_t (&pins)[N], uint8_t mode) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pinMode(pins[i], mode);
  }
}
```

Of course, with this you're free to use a range-based `for` loop if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, this solution works as expected, I appreciate you taking the time.